# How to deal with web component applications with different Bootstrap versions in the enclosing application?

Tags: bootstrap-4, web-component

In a web project which uses bootstrap 3 I have a web component which in turn uses bootstrap 4. The DOM of the web component is not locked, so there is no shadow dom.

How can I prevent the different styles from being overwritten and unwanted side effects from occurring?

Comment: Not, its one DOM, so exactly the same as running both Bootstrap versions in one page.

Answer (score 2):

That's what shadow DOM is for. Use shadow DOM, and put the Bootstrap 4 CSS inside of your web component.